# Get custom drawable parameters from xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-drawable, android-resources

I have my custom `Drawable` like this:

```
public class SeekBarBackgroundDrawable extends Drawable {
    Paint mBasePaint = null;

    public SeekBarBackgroundDrawable() {
        super();

        mBasePaint = new Paint();
        mBasePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mBasePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mBasePaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mBasePaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        mBasePaint.setColor(0xFF00FF00);

    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {    
        Rect r = getBounds();
        canvas.drawLine(r.left, canvas.getHeight()/2,r.right,canvas.getHeight()/2, mBasePaint);
    }
```

Now, this drawable is used in `layer-list` with parameters `color` and `width` like here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <cdev.mypreferences.SeekBarBackgroundDrawable
        android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/bg_color">

        </cdev.mypreferences.SeekBarBackgroundDrawable>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners android:radius="20dp"></corners>
                <solid android:color="@color/seekbar_progress"></solid>
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

How can I get parameters from this `xml` into `Drawable` class? I need to set `mBasePaint` stroke width and color?

Answer (score 1):

[Declaring custom drawables in `xml`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#Custom) is possible to do from API 24 onward, though I couldn't succeed to do that using the first approach mentioned in the docs.

Nevertheless, as the question relates to other aspect, I'll try to answer that part.

Adding this in your custom `Drawable` class would return the values you are interested in:

```
  private final int[] attrsArray = new int[] {
      android.R.attr.width,
      android.R.attr.color,
  };

  @Override public void inflate(@NonNull Resources r, @NonNull XmlPullParser parser,
      @NonNull AttributeSet attrs) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    super.inflate(r, parser, attrs);

    final TypedArray a = r.obtainAttributes(attrs, attrsArray);
    float width = a.getDimensionPixelSize(0, 0);
    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    int color = a.getColor(1, 0);

    a.recycle();
  }
```